# How can I advance the index of a pandas.dataframe by one quarter?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to shift the index of a pandas.dataframe by one quarter. The  dataframe looks like:

```
            ID   Nowcast  Forecast
1991-01-01   35   4144.70   4137.40
1991-01-01   40   4114.00   4105.00
1991-01-01   60   4135.00   4130.00
....
```

So far, I calculate the number of occurrences of the first timestamp `1991-01-01` and shifted the dataframe accordingly. The code is:

```
Stamps = df.index.unique()
zero = 0
for val in df.index:
    if val == Stamps[0]:
        zero = zero + 1
df = df.shift(zero)
```

The operation results in the following dataframe:

```
              ID   Nowcast  Forecast 
1991-04-01   35.0   4144.70   4137.40       
1991-04-01   40.0   4114.00   4105.00       
1991-04-01   60.0   4135.00   4130.00
```

The way I'm doing this strikes me as inefficient and error-prone. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you just trying to change the date index by three months? I would look into `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta()` or `pandas.Timedelta()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [pd.DateOffset()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
In [110]: df
Out[110]:
            ID  Nowcast  Forecast
1991-01-01  35   4144.7    4137.4
1991-01-01  40   4114.0    4105.0
1991-01-01  60   4135.0    4130.0

In [111]: df.index += pd.DateOffset(months=3)

In [112]: df
Out[112]:
            ID  Nowcast  Forecast
1991-04-01  35   4144.7    4137.4
1991-04-01  40   4114.0    4105.0
1991-04-01  60   4135.0    4130.0
```